# Remove downvoted question

Tags: discussion, down-votes, self-delete

Recently I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551413/dynamic-query-building-from-post-data-in-php) on Stack Overflow that has been downvoted. Yes, the solution for the problem I had was not the best, but I just asked to get a better understanding of some things and because I could not solve it myself after some searches.

I could say that it may not be so relevant for today's applications, but it could be used as reference for beginners (like me) even though the answers are not that relevant to what I'm asking.

Should I delete my question to eliminate the risk of getting more downvotes, or leave it for the sake of the ones that might be interested?

Comment: Consider looking into the *why* of its receiving down votes and fix that so that it becomes more useful to people finding it.  (Even if you don't fix it, the introspection will help you from writing down voted questions in the future)

Comment: The downvote means your question is not very neatly asked. Refer to the [`help` section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions. If you must, you should improve your question. Also, self-answering your own question is perfectly okay! Welcome to StackExchange!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting my own bad answer or comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71097/deleting-my-own-bad-answer-or-comment)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I delete my question to eliminate the risk of getting more
>   downvotes,

You can't really delete the question, since [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551413/dynamic-query-building-from-post-data-in-php) has [an upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20551595/961113). *(Also if your question has multiple answer with no upvotes, you can't delete it)*

> or leave it for the sake of the ones that might be interested?

Yes leave it *(you don't have any choice it seems)* , If someone finds it helpful, you may end up getting some upvotes. Try improving it if you think that the question can be improved.